# How to import npm package in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to import [ibantools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibantools) but it does not work with require. It says require is undefined. How can I use this package?

```
   const ibantools = require("ibantools")
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-knuth-y5xno?file=/src/App.js:91-115). You might have not installed the correct package, maybe show your package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use it like this:

```
import ibantools from "ibantools";
```

if the package you trying to import doesn't have a `default export` all you need to do imported as an object called `ibantools`

```
import * as ibantools from "ibantools";
```

and then use it like this `ibantools.whateverPropertyYoureLookingFor`

Comment: Then I get the Error: ibantools.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as ibantools from "ibantools";
```